# how can i optimise this code so that it takes lesser run time?

Tags: c

The original question is:

> A man has a rather old car being worth $2000.
>   He saw a secondhand car being worth $8000. He wants to keep his old
>   car until he can buy the secondhand one.
>
> He thinks he can save $1000 each month but the prices of his old car
>   and of the new one decrease of 1.5 percent per month. Furthermore the
>   percent of loss increases by a fixed 0.5 percent at the end of every
>   two months.
>
> Can you help him? Our man finds it difficult to make all these
>   calculations.
>
> How many months will it take him to save up enough money to buy the
>   car he wants, and how much money will he have left over?

I have implemented this so far how can I improve this code.

```
int main (){
    double percent=0.985; // the value by which the price of an item //reduces
    int startPriceOld=2000; //price of an item i want to sell
    int startPriceNew=8000;// price of an item i want to buy
    int savingperMonth=1000; // my monthly savings  
    int init=0;
    int mon=0; //no of months
    int saving=0;
    int diff=(saving*mon)-((pow(percent,mon))*(startPriceNew-startPriceOld));
      /*checking the condition when the money I have by selling my old item in addition to my savings will be greater than the money I need to buy my new item*/
      while(1)
      {
          mon++;
          startPriceOld=percent*startPriceOld;
          startPriceNew=percent*startPriceNew;
          saving=init+mon*savingperMonth;
          if(diff>0)
              {break;}
      }
          int arr[2];
          arr[0]=mon;
          arr[1]=diff;
          printf("%d",mon);
}
```

Comment: Your instructor probably wants you to solve this mathematically, not with a loop.

Comment: Maybe you should calculate `diff` inside the loop, so you'll have a chance for your program to end...

Comment: By "takes less runtime" do you mean "avoid an endless loop" ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "improve this code"? Does it work?

Comment: it is taking a lot of run time so can i reduce the run time?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with just math:

Price of the new car at each month:
`(new_car_cost)*(1-(0.015+0.005*floor(month/2)))^month`

Price of the old car at each month:
`(old_car_cost)*(1-(0.015+0.005*floor(month/2))^month`

Your salary:
`1000*month`

At the nth-month you will have:
`new_car_cost = old_car_cost+salary`

round up the month and you have solved the problem

You can also semplify the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Tried solving your issue and reached to this solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main (){
        float priceOld=2000; //price of an item i want to sell
        float priceNew=8000;// price of an item i want to buy
        int savingperMonth=1000; // my monthly savings
        int finalMonths = 0;
        float finalLeft = 0;
        int mon=0; //no of months
        for (mon = 1; mon<9;mon++){
            priceOld = priceOld - ((priceOld*15)/100);
            priceNew = priceNew - ((priceNew*15)/100);
            if( mon % 2 == 0 ){
                priceOld = priceOld - ((priceOld*5)/100);
                priceNew = priceNew - ((priceNew*5)/100);
            }
            if((priceOld + (savingperMonth*mon)) >= priceNew){
                finalMonths = mon;
                finalLeft = (priceOld + (savingperMonth*mon)) - priceNew;
                printf("Number of months: %d\n", finalMonths);
                printf("Final amount left: %f$", finalLeft);
                break;
            }
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

I think This will work fine for you.!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but what i am not able to understand is how is my algo different from yours?

Answer (score 0):

Output in main loop is for understanding what's happening there :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( )
{
    /* will store it in cents */

    unsigned int money_now = 0; 
    unsigned int salary = 100000;
    unsigned int money_left;

    unsigned int old_car_cost = 200000;
    unsigned int new_car_cost = 800000;

    float decr_percent = 0.015;
    float decr_percent_diff = 0.005;

    size_t months = 0;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        months++; /* Month has passed */

        money_now += salary; /* got salary*/
        old_car_cost -= old_car_cost * decr_percent; /* new cost of old car */
        new_car_cost -= new_car_cost * decr_percent; /* new cost of new car */

        /* 
            meanings:
            b - bugdet;
            p - percent;
            oc - old car cost;
            nc - new car cost.
        */
        printf("b:$%u;\tp:%.1f;\toc:$%u.%u;\tnc:$%u.%u\n", 
            money_now / 100, decr_percent * 100, old_car_cost / 100, old_car_cost % 100, new_car_cost / 100, new_car_cost % 100 );

        /* if ( ours money + old car's cost ) is enough for new car  */
        if ( new_car_cost <= ( money_now + old_car_cost) ) break;

        /*if it's end of every second month */
        if ( 0 == (months % 2) ) decr_percent += decr_percent_diff;
    }

    puts(""); /* newline */
    printf("It has been %lu months.\n", months );
    money_left = ( money_now + old_car_cost ) - new_car_cost;
    printf("Money left : $%u.%u\n", money_left / 100, money_left % 100);

    return 0;
}
```